# numpy inheriting ndarray object mutation

Tags: python, numpy, inheritance, mutation

i am inheriting from numpy ndarray and try to add *append* or *remove* methods.
Somehow the methods do not mutate the object. Any hints or solutions are welcome. The important parts of my class look like

```
import numpy as np

class Points3D(np.ndarray):
"""
Points3D is a general class for 3D Point operations and storage.
"""
CARTESIAN = "cartesian"
CYLINDER = "cylinder"
__slots__ = ['coordSys']

def __new__(cls, inputArray):
    if inputArray == []:
        inputArray = np.empty((0, 3))
    array = np.asarray(inputArray, dtype=np.float64)
    if 3 not in array.shape and inputArray:
        raise AttributeError("Input array must have one dimension equals 3. Its shape is %s though" % array.shape)
    if array.shape[0] == 3 and not array.shape[1] == 3:
        array = array.T
    obj = array.view(cls)
    return obj

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self._setCoordSys(kwargs.pop("coordSys", self.CARTESIAN))

def remove(self, point):
    """
    remove first occurrence of point.
    """
    # self = np.delete(self, self.indices(point)[0]) #will not work of course
    #but something like that

def indices(self, point):
    indices = []
    for i, p in enumerate(self):
        if all(p == point):
            indices.append(i)
    return indices

def _setCoordSys(self, coordSys):
    """
    Args:
        coordSys (str): see above __init__ for the constants you can set.
    """
    self.coordSys = coordSys
```

I wonder whether methods like ***array_wrap*** have to be implemented.
If there would be an example it would help a lot.
Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: You'd probably be better off writing a class that holds an `np.ndarray` in an instance variable than subclassing `np.ndarray` itself.

Comment: I thought about that. I wanted to use the efficient way of saving for numpy arrays though.

Comment: Write your own save or pickle that uses the array's own method.

Comment: There are loads of advantages, not only saving efficiency for inheriting from np.ndarray. For example slicing and indexing. Of course you can wrap everything around a class that holds the array in an instance. Though i would like to inherit since i think it is the most pythonic way.